# Получение id задачи через python-код от celery

Tags: python, django, celery

Задача состоит в следующем: мне необходимо вывести на страницу django проекта статус текущих задач celery, а так же очередей задач, если таковые есть. На данный момент добрался до самих задач в приложении django:

```
from bgp.celery import app
tasks = app.tasks.values()
print tasks[0].AsyncResult(tasks[0].request.id).state
```

На что получаю результат:

```
ValueError: AsyncResult requires valid id, not <type 'NoneType'>
```

Если выводить id всех задач, коих 33 штуки, то у них у всех будет значение None. С другой стороны, когда я вызываю задачу через call by name, то задаче вроде как этот самый id присваивается. Собственно вопрос: правильно ли я понимаю, что если задача celery находится не на исполнении, то и id у неё будет None и статус вычислить нельзя?
Попутный вопрос: как можно посмотреть статус завершившихся задач через python код и посмотреть ошибки через python код в задачах, если таковые возникли?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать `inspect`.

```
from celery.task.control import inspect

i = inspect()
i.active() # вернет все активные таски
i.reserved() # вернет таски которые ждут своей очереди
```

В ответе вы сможете взять id каждой таски.
Примерный вариант ответа(половина полей опущена для краткости):

```
{
'celery@p285849.kvmvps': [{
    'args': '(227,)',
    'time_start': 839296.465949286,
    'name': 'apps.mailer.tasks.mailing',
    'kwargs': '{}',
    'id':'87b1bd36-185c-497f-a194-7447be81c230',
    'worker_pid': 906
}, ...]}
```

Comment: Вы правы! А не подскажете как можно посмотреть завершённые задачи и их ошибки (если есть).

Comment: @anderson Для этого нужно настроить `result_backend`, Вот здесь об этом можно почитать, http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/3.1/configuration.html#celery-result-backend . К примеру, можно взять postgres как backend и celery создаст там 2 таблицы `task` и `group`, оттуда можно будет брать данные о завершенных тасках

Comment: Для тех кто может это читать дополню: если правильно подключить flower к вашему проекту, то там будет вся интересующая информация. в исходниках flower можно найти много интересного